# How do I implement thread wait notify?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is the code I wrote. I tried many ways but it doesn't work. Please help `pause()` method works but `continue()` doesn't.

```
public abstract class Figure implements Runnable {

    public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.ORANGE;
    public static final int DEFAULT_X = 30;
    public static final int DEFAULT_Y = 30;
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 50;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 50;
    /**
     *
     */
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;
    /**
     * speed per OX projection
     */
    private int xS;
    /**
     * speed per OY projection
     */
    private int yS;
    private Thread t;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private boolean isPaused;
    private FigureCanvas panel;

    // START CONSTRUCTORS
    // WE can add more constructor with other parameter group if it is necessary
    protected Figure() {
        this(DEFAULT_X, DEFAULT_Y, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, DEFAULT_COLOR);

    }

    protected Figure(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this(x, y, width, height, DEFAULT_COLOR);
    }

    protected Figure(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;


    }
// END OF CONSTRUCTORS

    //Start getters and setters block
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        if (width < 0) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect parameter error: width can not be negative ");
            return;
        }
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        if (height < 0) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect parameter error: height can not be negative ");
            return;
        }
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
//End of getters and setters block

    public abstract boolean isBelong(int x, int y);

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("In RUN method");
        while (isRunning) {
            System.out.println("running");
        }
    }

    public void move(int xS, int yS) {
        x += xS;
        y += yS;
    }

    public void move() {
        xS = 1;
        yS = 1;
        move(xS, yS);
    }

    public void stop() {
        // TODO stop thread
    }

    public void continueRun() {
//      ToDO notify
        synchronized (t) {
            isRunning = true;

            t.notify();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        // TODO organize wait
        synchronized (t) {
            try {
                isRunning = false;
                t.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
//  TODO    start new thread and callits start method
        t = new Thread(this);
        isRunning = true;
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Figure{"
                + "x=" + x
                + ", y=" + y
                + ", width=" + width
                + ", height=" + height
                + ", color=" + color
                + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: because `continueRun()` notifies the `this` object, while `pause()` method is waiting for signal on `t`

Comment: Also, the run() method reads the isRunning flag without synchronization, and I really don't understand what the pause() is waiting for: it doesn't do anything after it is awaken. And wait() should always be called in a loop, as the documentation explains.

Comment: @JBNizet right, and `isRunning` flag should be volatile too.

Comment: pause() method must wait thread and then when continue() will called it must wake up and continue his work

Comment: @Ashot We see, but a thread should call the `continueRun()` when the first thread is waiting for some resume signal. the code is incompleted of course.

Comment: the main problem that i can't fix this problem..... i have only one thread.. and i want make it wait and then notify ...

Comment: @Ashot so this example may help http://arashmd.blogspot.nl/2013/06/java-threading.html#ex3, I learned it myself from this guy

Comment: OK thanks I will try understand its already second day that I can't fix this problem !!!

Comment: You may also find the following article useful on how to deal with InterruptedException:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Comment: As you are modifying the question a lot... does it still not work? Have you tried to debug the code in eclipse?

Comment: yes I have tried but no result i cant understand what is the problem the thread is waiting but not notify !

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting on the object `t`, so to wake up you need a notify on the object `t` too!

If you are trying to do something like [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/), you should not forget that the notify in that case is executed ***in*** the b Object.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for "pausable runnables", I find it easier to maintain. Here is the pattern I use:

```
public class Q22569411 implements Runnable {

private volatile boolean paused;
private volatile boolean stop;
private final Semaphore pauseLock = new Semaphore(0);

@Override
public void run() {

    while (!stop) {
        work();
        if (paused) {
            System.out.println("Pausing work.");
            try { 
                pauseLock.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Pause interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Stopped running");
}

protected void work() {

    System.out.println("Working");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("Work interrupted.");
    }
}

public boolean isPaused() {
    return paused;
}

public void setPaused(boolean pause) {

    if (this.paused == pause) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.paused) {
        paused = false;
        pauseLock.release();
    } else {
        // Remove previous release in case this method is called repeatedly
        pauseLock.tryAcquire();
        paused = true;
    }
}

public void stopRunning() {

    stop = true;
    pauseLock.release();
}

}
```